# Web Font Loader multiple font weights

Tags: webfonts

I am using Web Font Loader to load a font from Google webfonts but it seems to only load the 400 weight. I wish to included 300, 400, 700 but cannot find a way to do it.

```
  WebFontConfig = {
    google: { 
      families: ['Open Sans'] 
    }
  };

  (function() {
    var wf = document.createElement('script');
    wf.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http') +
        '://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.4.7/webfont.js';
    wf.type = 'text/javascript';
    wf.async = 'true';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
  })();
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found this solution which worked.

```
  WebFontConfig = {
    google: { 
      families: ['Open Sans:300,400,700']
    },
```

Comment: What about font families that have an italic variant?

Comment: a normal case with reglar/bold and italic variants:
families: ['Open Sans:400,700,400italic,700italic']

Answer (score 2):

As mentionned by Keith Power, you have to add types. But to get it work with all providers (and most important with your custom font), you have to use the [Font Variation Description](https://github.com/typekit/fvd) :

```
WebFontConfig = {
  custom: {
    families: ['My Font', 'My Other Font:n4,i4,n7'],
  }
};
```

- n4 : regular
- n7 : bold
- i4 : italic
- i7 : bold-italic
- ...